# Docker with Spring Boot application stuck at AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext on RaspberryPi

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

What I'm trying to do is to run simple spring boot application inside a docker container (`openjdk:8-jre`) via docker-compose. The code works fine on my machine (macbook pro). The problem is when I'm trying to run the same piece of docker containers on my raspberry pi with raspbian. It's stuck just before logging `Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)`.
The container with spring application only does `java -jar` and exposes port `8080` for my another container (on port `8888`) with my single page application. Does anyone had similar problem or know how to fix this?

Here are the logs for running the container on raspberrypi:

`` wfeservices    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
wfeservices    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
wfeservices    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
wfeservices    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
wfeservices    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
wfeservices    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
wfeservices    |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)
wfeservices    |
wfeservices    | 2018-08-22 20:36:24 - Starting Application v1.0-SNAPSHOT on 4b7fcb7b344c with PID 7 (/wfeservices.jar started by root in /)
wfeservices    | 2018-08-22 20:36:24 - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
wfeservices    | 2018-08-22 20:36:28 - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1412c2f: startup date [Wed Aug 22 20:36:28 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy ``

Comment: Have you tried starting your application with `--debug` or even `--trace`? As an aside, for a tiny environment like a Raspberry Pi, I would suggest using Jetty instead of Tomcat as it's a bit lighter. Spring startup phase is very CPU and IO intensive - it may be that the Pi is simply taking a long time.

Comment: In addition, note that anything prior to Java 9 does not natively support containerization, meaning that the JVM may be setting a *much* higher CPU/IO/Memory allowance/initial values than it should (i.e. that of the host system, not that which is allocated to the container).

Comment: Looks like it starts when I'm building and running `docker-compose up --build` with extra flag `-d` (running in background). Then I can see in logs that the spring boot applications starts in 200seconds. When I'm not running in background it's stuck at the `root of context hierarchy`

Comment: Are you limiting the docker containers in any way (cpu, memory, etc.)?

Comment: @user991710 no limitations

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem on AWS ECS then I realized that I had way to little memory so I increased the memory to 4096 megabytes and it worked.